# Explain the code in reactive function

Tags: r, shiny, dt

```
1 dat <- reactive({
2    input$myslider
3    mtcars[1:input$myslider,c("mpg", "cyl", "disp")]
4    
5  })
6 
7  output$mytable <- DT::renderDataTable(dat(),
8                                        options = list(paging=FALSE, scrollX =TRUE),
9                                        rownames=TRUE, filter = "top"))
}
```

Hi everyone, I am fairly a beginner at R, and I am learning the application of Shiny. I found this app code on Zevross to create an interactive table with DT. I couldn't understand the working of the code. It would be great if someone explained to me how this code works in the server function. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Line 2: Redundant, you can remove it as it only prints the value of `myslider` input.

Line 3: Subsets object `mtcars` from row 1 to whatever the number on the slider is and columns `mpg`, `cyl` and `disp`. The result is a data.frame of n×3.

Line 4: Empty. :)

Line 7: Pass reactive environment `dat`, where a data.frame is generated based on slider input, to function `renderDataTable`. [Options are passed on](https://github.com/rstudio/DT/blob/master/man/dataTableOutput.Rd#L33) to datatable (see all available [options here](https://github.com/rstudio/DT/blob/master/man/datatable.Rd#L6)). This line attaches the result to output which is drawn in your shiny app.

Comment: Cool, thanks Roman for that. :) It was helpful